# CocoaLibSpotify fails to compile in XCode 4.6 / iOS 6.1

Tags: spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

CocoaLibSpotify fails compilation in XCode 6.5 Preview 2 / iOS 6.1 SDK with this error:

> /LibSpotify/spotify-cocoalibspotify-a6c2579/iOS Library/../common/SPImage.m:55:65: error: strong property 'session' may not also be declared __unsafe_unretained
>   @property (nonatomic, readwrite) __unsafe_unretained SPSession *session;
>                                                                   ^
>   1 error generated.

Is there a safe work-around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry about that — I just pushed a fix to the `dev` branch to the CocoaLibSpotify repository on GitHub.

The fix is to remove the `assign` part of the `session` property declaration in `SPImage.h`.